# why is my Lid Switch not logging properly?

Tags: debian, systemd, firmware

after boot and log-in I can call `journalctl` and see Lid Switch events:

```
# journalctl | grep -a "Lid"
Mar 22 09:18:19 debian kernel: input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2
Mar 22 09:18:19 debian kernel: ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
Mar 22 09:18:20 debian systemd-logind[599]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Lid Switch)
```

but if I open and close my laptops's lid nothing is added to the output no matter how often I do it. The lid action doesn't log any further entry in `journalctl`. Thus, my screen stays on when I close the lid.

what is causing this? how can I fix it?

---

**Update:**

```
# evtest /dev/input/event1
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x5 version 0x0
Input device name: "Lid Switch"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 5 (EV_SW)
    Event code 0 (SW_LID) state 0
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
^C
```

```
# libinput debug-events
-event2   DEVICE_ADDED     Power Button                      seat0 default group1  cap:k
-event3   DEVICE_ADDED     Video Bus                         seat0 default group2  cap:k
-event1   DEVICE_ADDED     Lid Switch                        seat0 default group3  cap:S
-event9   DEVICE_ADDED     HDA Intel PCH Headphone           seat0 default group4  cap:
-event10  DEVICE_ADDED     HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3       seat0 default group4  cap:
-event8   DEVICE_ADDED     HDA Intel PCH Mic                 seat0 default group4  cap:
-event0   DEVICE_ADDED     AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      seat0 default group5  cap:k
-event4   DEVICE_ADDED     SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad        seat0 default group6  cap:p  size 84x42mm tap(dl off) left scroll-nat scroll-2fg-edge dwt-on
-event5   DEVICE_ADDED     TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint             seat0 default group7  cap:p left scroll-nat scroll-button
-event7   DEVICE_ADDED     ThinkPad Extra Buttons            seat0 default group8  cap:k
-event0   KEYBOARD_KEY     +28.35s  *** (-1) pressed
 event0   KEYBOARD_KEY     +29.16s  *** (-1) pressed
^C
```

Comment: Does `evtest /dev/input/event1` show anything?

Comment: nope... neither `libinput debug-event`

Comment: Is there an available BIOS update for your laptop? Just to spell things out, I trust you opened and shut the lid whilst running evtest. You are soon going to be delving into the murky world of ACPI, hidden virtual machines which can take control of your laptop and other horrors.

Comment: hahahaha! well, I have already opened that door: https://wp.puri.sm/posts/reverse-engineering-the-intel-management-engine-romp-module/   ...  I'll have a look on the BIOS update, and post back but it doesn't seem easy to find out. First quick search was unsuccessful... And yes, ACPI is still very cryptical to me. ... The machine in question do have an Intel i5 processor

Comment: @scjorge Did you have any success with this? I have a T480s and have the same problem. The sensor is working, but the events aren't registered in linux.

Comment: hi! sorry, no. my laptop died. I decided to reboot it and never came up again :/ It was an Edge E520 1143B I wonder if it is fixable, but I have no knowledge and I am concerned of investing too much in old hardware. it was also not the best at its time...